# Filtering collection with Doctrine Criteria by property of @Embedded entity

Tags: doctrine-orm, criteria, api-platform.com

I have `OneToMany` relationship between `User` and `Call`s entities. `Call` in its turn has `@Embedded` property `cdr` represented by `CallDetailRecord` class. I need to filter out collection of calls by one of the properties of `CallDetailRecord` class. If I use dot-notation (like `'cdr.disposition'`)  — `Undefined property: Mock_Call_ccc3cbd4::$cdr.disposition`. Underscore-notation — same result. Is it possible in general to use Criteria API for this case?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there is `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::filter()` method which solved the issue completely.